# printf format specifiers in awk does not work for multiple parameters

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, awk

I'm trying to Write a program script in Bash named example7
Which accepts as parameters: a file name (lets call it file 1) and a list of
Numbers (below we'll call it List 1) and what the program needs to do is to print as output the columns from
File 1 after rescheduling them to right or left by the numbers in list 1. (This is obtainable by using the printf command of awk).

Example

Suppose the contents of an F1 file are:

```
A abcd ddd eee zz tt
ab gggwe 12 88 iii jjj
yaara yyzz 12abcd xyz x y z
```

After running the program by command:

```
example7 F1 -8 -7 6 4
```

Output:

```
A       abcd      ddd eee
ab      gggwe      12 88
yaara   yyzz   12abcd xyz
```

In the example above between `A` and `ABCD` there are 7 spaces, between `abcd` and `ddd`
there are 6 spaces and between `ddd` and `eee`
there is one space.

Another example:

After running the program by command:

```
example7 F1 -8 -7 6 4 5
```

Output:

```
A       abcd      ddd eee   zz
ab      gggwe      12  88  iii
yaara   yyzz   12abcd xyz    x
```

In the example above between `A` and `ABCD` there are 7 spaces, between `abcd` and `ddd`
there are 6 spaces, between `ddd` and `eee`
there is one space, between `eee` and `zz` there are 3 spaces, between `88` and `iii`
there are two spaces, between `xyz` and `x` there are 4 spaces.

I've tried doing something like this:

```
file=$1
shift
awk '{printf "%'$1's\n" ,$1}' $file
```

but it only works for one number and one parameter and I don't know how I can do it for multiple columns and multiple parameters..
any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set an `awk` variable to all the remaining parameters, then split it and loop over them.

```
file=$1
shift
awk -v sizes="$*" '{words = split(sizes, s); for(i = 1; i <= words; i++) printf("%" s[i] "s", $i); print ""; }' "$file"
```

It's generally wrong to try to substitute a shell variable directly into an `awk` script. You should prefer to set an `awk` variable using `-v`, and then use `awk`'s own string concatenation operation, as I did with `s[i]`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I ran the example [ex7 F1 -8 -7 6 4 ] it works except for the first column.                                        The first column is not formatting correctly  and its taking words from other columns and combining.

Comment: Looping over array keys doesn't necessarily go in order. I changed it to a numeric loop.

Comment: `-v words="$#" '{split(sizes, s)` = `'{words=split(sizes, s)`, and `printf("%" s[i] "s", $i)` = `printf "%*s", s[i], $i` and when you write `printf("\n")` you're printing what you assume the ORS value will be, `"\n"`, so just use `print ""` instead and it WILL print the ORS value (plus it's very slightly briefer/simpler). Also, instead of using a variable `words` at all you could write `{split(sizes, s); for(i = 1; i in s; i++)`

Comment: I originally used NF instead of `words`, someone else edited that in (in case there are fewer parameters than fields), I agree your method is simpler. I have an old, possibly bad, habit of using `\n` explicitly, just like in other languages, since `ORS` is practically never something else.

Comment: Your last form looks too easy to confuse with `for (i in s)`, which I tried but it didn't process them in sequential order. I'll leave it as `i <= words`, I think it's clearer.